# Does 'now' in Twilio flows *really resolve to Pacific Time (PT) which has variable offsets to UTC?

Tags: time, twilio

OK so, as anyone who has used Twilio flows will be aware....
'now' (which afaik is the only way you can get the current time), returns a datetime
Pacific Time:

"When using the now keyword instead of a specific date, the resulting time will be output in US Pacific Time, not UTC." -> From the Twilio Liquid reference.

Pacific Time, however, *can change depending on winter/summer.
And could be either PST (Pacific Standard Time) or PDT (Pacific Daylight Time).

Does anyone know precisely which time is returned and if it changes or not for winter/summer?

Thanks
-Pat

Nothing has gone wrong *yet, need to know if I will need to adjust if/when PST->PDT or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "now" will result in US Pacific Time regardless of your region. And it will adjust for DST.